# JWT Token Verification FastAPI SQLAlchemy payload['sub'] returning None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jwt, fastapi

I'm trying to mimic this code snippet which is using FastAPI and tortoise orm into SQLAlachemy orm:

```
@auth_router.get("/verify/{token}")
async def verify(token: str):
    invalid_token_error = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid token")
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM)
    except jwt.JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Token has expired")
    if payload['scope'] != 'registration':
        raise invalid_token_error
    user = await users.UserModel.get_or_none(id=payload['sub'])
    if not user or str(user.confirmation) != payload['jti']:
        raise invalid_token_error
    if user.is_active:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User already activated")
    user.confirmation = None
    user.is_active = True
    await user.save()
    return await users.User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user)
```

SQLAlchemy Implementation:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status
from fastapi import Depends
from jose import jwt

from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate, ShowUser
from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users
from core.auth import Auth
from core.hashing import Hasher
from core.mailer import Mailer
from core.config import Settings
from depends import get_user_db

router = APIRouter()

get_settings = Settings()


@router.post("/", response_model=ShowUser)
async def create_user(form_data: UserCreate = Depends(), users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    if await users.check_user(email=form_data.email) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User already exists"
        )
    elif await users.check_username(username=form_data.username) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Username already exists"
        )

    new_user = User(email=form_data.email,hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password))
    confirmation = Auth.get_confirmation_token(new_user.id)
    print(confirmation)
    new_user.confirmation = confirmation["jti"]


    try:
        Mailer.send_confirmation_message(confirmation["token"], form_data.email)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail="Email couldn't be send. Please try again."
        )
    return await users.register_user(form_data)

@router.get("/verify/{token}")
async def verify(token: str, users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    invalid_token_error = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid Token")
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, get_settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[get_settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM])
        print(payload['sub'])
    except jwt.JWSError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Token has Expired")
    if payload['scope'] != 'registration':
        raise invalid_token_error
    print(payload['sub'])
    user = await users.get_user_by_id(id=str(payload['sub']))
    print(user)
    print('hello2')
    if not user or await users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation)) != payload['jti']:
        print('hello')
        raise invalid_token_error
    if user.is_active:
        print('hello2')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User already Activated")
    user.confirmation = None
    user.is_active = True
    return await users.register_user(user)
```

When I hit the endpoint `@router.get("/verify/{token}")` and control gets to `user = await users.get_user_by_id(id=payload['sub'])` it is just return `None` instead of id hence I get the `"detail": Invaild Token`. Anyone can point out what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my rest of the API structure:

**auth.py**

```
from jose import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from core.config import Settings
from pydantic import UUID4
import uuid
from passlib.context import CryptContext

settings = Settings()


class Auth:
    password_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

    @classmethod
    def get_password_hash(cls, password: str) -> str:
        return cls.password_context.hash(password)

    @staticmethod
    def get_token(data: dict, expires_delta: int):
        pass
        to_encode = data.copy()
        to_encode.update({
            "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=expires_delta),
            "iss": settings.PROJECT_NAME
        })
        return jwt.encode(
            to_encode,
            settings.SECRET_KEY,
            algorithm=settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_confirmation_token(user_id: UUID4):
        jti = uuid.uuid4()
        claims = {
            "sub": str(user_id),
            "scope": "registration",
            "jti": str(jti)
        }
        return {
            "jti": jti,
            "token": Auth.get_token(
                claims,
                settings.REGISTRATION_TOKEN_LIFETIME
            )
        }
```

**users.py:**

```
import uuid
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from db.base_class import Base


class User(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(255), nullable=False,)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    confirmation = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    jobs = relationship("Job", back_populates="owner")
```

**users_data_access_layer.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select


from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from core.hashing import Hasher


db_session = Session

class Users():
    
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        self.db_session = db_session

    
            #print('user created')

    async def register_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
        email=user.email,
        hashed_password=user.password,
        is_active = False,
        is_superuser=False
        )
        
        self.db_session.add(new_user)
        await self.db_session.flush()
        return new_user

    async def check_user(self, email: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.email==email))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def check_username(self, username: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.username==username))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()
    
    async def get_user_by_id(self, id: str):
        item = await self.db_session.get(User, id)
        return item

    async def get_confirmation_uuid(self, confirmation_uuid:str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(str(User.confirmation)==confirmation_uuid))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist
```

**schemas/users.py**

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

class ShowUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    is_active: bool

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Comment: `user` is None or `payload['sub']` is None ?

Comment: @fchancel `payload['sub']` is None

Comment: Where is the function or endpoint where you called `get_confirmation_token` ?

Comment: @fchancel In registration route `confirmation = Auth.get_confirmation_token(new_user.id)` I updated the code with registration route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from this line in `async def create_user`

`new_user = User(email=form_data.email,hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password))`

Your User class must contain a username since `nullable=False`. However, when creating the user, you only provide him with an email and a password. So your variable new_user does not contain a user. So when you do:
`confirmation = Auth.get_confirmation_token(new_user.id)`
`new_user.id` is set to None. So your sub token actually contains None.

So, replace :

`new_user = User(email=form_data.email,hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password))`

with :

`new_user = User(email=form_data.email,username=form_data.username,hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password))`

At this point, you have created an instance of the mapped class. And as explained in the SQLAlchemy ORM documentation. At this point the id constantly returns None. We say that the instance is pending. No SQL has been issued yet and the object is not represented by a row in the database yet (hence the reason why the id is none). So to make our User instance persist. Session.add() is needed.

And in order to complete our creation and validate our transaction with the database. Now we just have to Session.commit()

So to summarize you have to do:

```py
session = Session()
new_user = User(email=form_data.email,username=form_data.username,hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password))
session.add(new_user)
session.commit()
```

After that, you will have access to the id of your User.

Regarding the creation of the Session and in order to find more information about the process, I encourage you to go and see the documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#create-a-schema

**EDIT** *In response to the above comment regarding an AttributeError*

In your code, you try to register the user 3 times. The first time within your `create_user` route (this is the code I am talking about in my answer). A second time, at the end of this endpoint by calling `return await users.register_user(form_data)` and a third time by calling `return await users.register_user(user)` within `async def verify`.
The error comes from the third call, since your `register_user` function takes `UserCreate` as a parameter and at that moment, you pass it an instance of User, which does not correspond to the requested format. So effectively `user.password` does not exist, since your instance of User does not have an attribute named `password`.

It seems necessary to me to review the logic of your code.

Comment: No change it still returning `None`

Comment: have you looked at what the new_user variable contains?

Comment: Yeah it contains the object `<db.models.users.User object at 0x0000014D26A3E280>` and I also looked at `new_user.id` it is still returning `None`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'password'` now it is giving me this error when I try to commit to the database `await users.register_user(new_user)` `File ".\db\repository\users_data_access_layer.py", line 26, in register_user
    hashed_password=user.password,
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'password'`

Comment: I think I have to post the new question with these new errors rise.Can you give a look at?

Comment: Yes, I think it seems necessary to conclude this question since the answer has been given (namely the invalid Token problem) and open a new topic.
I will watch this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. And here is the link of the new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385681/fastapi-attributeerror-user-object-has-no-attribute-password