# FastAPI AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a FastAPI project in which I am using Async SQLAlchemy orm and postgresql as db. Basically it is a simple CRUD based Job Board I've manage to create the CRUD operations successfully and they are working as I expected. The issue I'm stumbled upon is user authentication I'm trying to implementing authentication via JWT on user registration, user will fill out the fields, username, email and password then an verification email will be sent to that user email to verify the JWT token after that `is_active` field will be `True` which is by default `False`. I tried couple of ways but couldn't succeed, I'm having difficulty adding the user to the database.

**routes/route_user.py:**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status
from fastapi import Depends
from jose import jwt

from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate, ShowUser
from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users
from core.auth import Auth
from core.hashing import Hasher
from core.mailer import Mailer
from core.config import Settings
from depends import get_user_db

router = APIRouter()

get_settings = Settings()


@router.post("/", response_model=ShowUser)
async def create_user(form_data: UserCreate = Depends(), users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    if await users.check_user(email=form_data.email) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User already exists"
        )
    elif await users.check_username(username=form_data.username) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Username already exists"
        )

    new_user = User(email=form_data.email,
                username=form_data.username,
                hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(form_data.password)
                )
    await users.register_user(new_user)
    print(new_user)
    confirmation = Auth.get_confirmation_token(new_user.id)
    print(confirmation)
    new_user.confirmation = confirmation["jti"]


    try:
        Mailer.send_confirmation_message(confirmation["token"], form_data.email)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail="Email couldn't be send. Please try again."
        )
    return await users.register_user(form_data)

@router.get("/verify/{token}")
async def verify(token: str, users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    invalid_token_error = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid Token")
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, get_settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[get_settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM])
        print(payload['sub'])
    except jwt.JWSError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Token has Expired")
    if payload['scope'] != 'registration':
        raise invalid_token_error
    print(payload['sub'])
    user = await users.get_user_by_id(id=payload['sub'])
    print(user)
    print('hello2')
    if not user or await users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation)) != payload['jti']:
        print('hello')
        raise invalid_token_error
    if user.is_active:
        print('hello2')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User already Activated")
    user.confirmation = None
    user.is_active = True
    return await users.register_user(user)
```

the route above outputs the Attribute error:

```
File ".\db\repository\users_data_access_layer.py", line 26, in register_user
    hashed_password=user.password,
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'password'
```

**user_data_access_layer.py**

This is where all db communications are happening. Here I think I need some kind of `save method` to add to db for convenience but I don't know how to implement it. I tried something like this:

```
from core.hashing import Hasher
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists


from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from core.hashing import Hasher


db_session = Session

class Users():
    
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        self.db_session = db_session
    async def save(self):
        if self.id == None:
           self.db_session.add(self)
        return await self.db_session.flush()
    
            #print('user created')

    async def register_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
        email=user.email,
        hashed_password=user.password,
        is_active = False,
        is_superuser=False
        )
        self.db_session.add(new_user)
        await self.db_session.flush()
        return new_user

    async def check_user(self, email: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.email==email))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def check_username(self, username: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.username==username))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()
    
    async def get_user_by_id(self, id: int):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.id==id)
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def get_confirmation_uuid(self, confirmation_uuid:str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(str(User.confirmation)==confirmation_uuid))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist
```

**schemas/users.py**

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    username: str 
    email: EmailStr
    password: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

class ShowUser(UserBase):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    is_active: bool

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

**models/users.py**

```
import uuid
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from db.base_class import Base


class User(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    confirmation = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    jobs = relationship("Job", back_populates="owner")
```

**depends.py**

```
from db.session import async_session
from db.repository.jobs_data_access_layer import JobBoard
from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users

async def get_job_db():
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            yield JobBoard(session)

async def get_user_db():
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            yield Users(session)
```

Since this is all new stuff and wherever I reached I hit a wall and I'm working on this project for weeks now and couldn't find my way around it yet so any assistance would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different problems in the code. Firstly some calls to the method of the class model/Users are called with the wrong parameters. Indeed, some are called with a User object as parameter while those are expecting a Pydantic UserCreate model. So, when you send a `User` object instead of the Pydantic model, the `password` attribute does not exist.
Secondly, afterwards, other problems will appear, since your methods to retrieve a User object actually return a list (ChunkIterator). However, you make comparisons as if you were receiving an object.

I took the liberty of proposing an alternative by reformulating some of your code.

Now, I have created methods to save eventual modification of users in your DB, and created some methods that return a user according to different criteria (id, username, email) except that contrary to your code, those return an object (or None) instead of a list.

user_data_access_layer.py

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException, status

from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from db_config import SESSION
from auth import Auth

class Users():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    async def save(cls, user_instance):
        try:
            SESSION.add(user_instance)
            SESSION.commit()
        except Exception as error:
            SESSION.rollback()
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_id(cls, id):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.id == id).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_username(cls, username):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.username == username).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_email(cls, email):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.email == email).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_confirmation(cls, confirmation):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.confirmation == confirmation).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def create_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
                        email=user.email,
                        hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(user.password)
                        )
        cls.save(new_user)
        return new_user
```

As you can see, I removed the Session creation from your layer file and put it in a global variable, in a separate file.

db_config.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

ENGINE: Engine = create_engine(your_config_url, pool_pre_ping=True)
SESSION: Session = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)()
```

And to conclude, here is your endpoint updated according to the proposed code. I have added comments inside it to make it easier to understand.

route.py

```py
@router.post("/", response_model=ShowUser)
async def create_user(form_data: UserCreate = Depends(), users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    # CHECK IF USER ALREADY EXISTS
    if await Users.get_user_by_email(email=form_data.email) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User already exists"
        )
    # CHECK IF USERNAME ALREADY EXISTS
    elif await Users.get_user_by_username(username=form_data.username) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Username already exists"
        )

    # CREATE USER WITH USERS METHOD
    # now the hashing of the password is done directly in the creation method
    new_user = await Users.create_user(form_data)
    
    # GET TOKEN
    # we no longer create a new uid for JTI, but use the one created automatically during user creation
    # so I modified the get_confirmation_token function so that it takes the user's JTI uid as a parameter
    confirmation_token = Auth.get_confirmation_token(
                            new_user.id,
                            new_user.confirmation)
```

Answer (score 0):

table has not password, table has only hashed_password

```
new_user = User(username=user.username,
email=user.email,
hashed_password=user.hashed_password,
is_active = False,
is_superuser=False
)
```